# django-admin: How to redirect to another URL after Object save?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django Admin, saving an Object always goes back to it's List of Objects.
Now i want to go to the List of Invoice-Objects upon saving a Payment-Object.

**I tried several things:**

In admin.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Payment)
def custom_redirect(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/sales/invoice')
```

OR

```
class PaymentAdmin(VersionAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/sales/invoice')
```

Instead of HttpResponseRedirect i tried using redirect() , but also with no effect.
On inserting wrong code into post_save i get an error message - so it does get triggered, but the redirect does not happen.

Any hints would be very apreciated - as i'm stuck for days on this "simple" problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can override the [`response_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) and [`response_change`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change) methods.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class PaymentAdmin(VersionAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        return redirect('/admin/sales/invoice')

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        return redirect('/admin/sales/invoice')
```

It isn't possible to return a response from inside a signal handler. You don't want to override `change_view` because that handles saving the form as well as returning the response.

Comment: The self argument is missing in the response_change example.