# Django admin override changelist url

Tags: django, django-admin

I've a proxymodel  in the admin and want to change it's default changelist_view from:

> django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view
>
> "myapp_mymodel_changelist"

to

> "myapp_Othermodel_changelist"

I've tried to override the method:

```
class mymodelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        return OthermodelAdmin.changelist_view(self,request, extra_context=None)
```

but still get back to same changeview.

I I override urls:

```
 def urls(self):
     urls = self.get_urls()
     urls =+ OthermodelAdmin.urls()
     return urls
```

> it says thereis a circular url

how can I do the redirect?

Comment: solved looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230437/django-admin-how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-object-save/42231015#42231015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-admin: How to redirect to another URL after Object save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230437/django-admin-how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-object-save)