# Best Way To Manage Model Instances Based On Attributes In Django Admin

Tags: python, django, admin

Lets say I have a model:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   status = Models.CharField(choices=Choices)
```

Lets say Choices gives the choices of Reviewed, Rejected, Accepted.

I want to be able to declare a choice for an instance in the admin panel, and once I save the choice, the instance is moved to another section, preferably another admin folder such as Reviewed Applicants, Rejected Applicant, etc etc.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230437/django-admin-how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-object-save) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230437/django-admin-how-to-redirect-to-another-url-after-object-save), This should solve your problem

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class PaymentAdmin(VersionAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        return redirect('/admin/sales/invoice')

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        return redirect('/admin/sales/invoice')
```

and here're the official [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add) links

Comment: Thanks, this is along the right lines, although I am still struggling to implement the moving of instances based on the choices attribute.